# Android Studio UI Text disappearing and glirtchy

Tags: user-interface, android-studio

Android Studio was working fine but when I moved my sdk to another internal drive and gave the proper path to Android Studio and restarted its gradle, it started glitching on the UI level. please find the photo attached.

I tried updating it (to the current version 1.4) but that didn't fix the problem.

Any idea?

[image: Android Studio 1.4 ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found a Solution!

Theme: Dracula

Change Font Presentation to: 8

and it will work!

Note that you can revert back to Font Size 24 and it will still work :)

Answer (score 1):

I had same behavior, just after installing Android Studio for the first time.

In my case, the behavior becomes normal when I turn off ClearType text.

I am using Windows 7, and this is how I turned it off:

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display 
=> Adjust ClearType text
=> uncheck [ ] Turn on ClearType
```

Comment: yes that worked! however i reverted back to ClearType Text because the font was awful! is there a solution with ClearType ON? thank youu